# 15.04 Could not set configuration for CRTC63. Booting lid closed

Tags: dell, display, laptop, 15.04, display-manager

When I boot my Dell Latitude E7440 laptop, an error dialog is show on login screen:

```
Could not set configuration for CRTC63.
```

If the lid is closed during boot, the disk `crypto login` is shown on external displays but the Ubuntu login screen does not appear before I open the lid and close it again.